# How to define http-listener' `max-parameter` at the application-level, not server-level?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-16

## The problem

We're facing the [UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241526) issue.

(We use WilfdFly 16).

## What we tried, and worked, but is not acceptable

We followed the solution in [UT000047](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/241526), i.e. increase the `max-parameters` of the `http-listener` in the "standalone.xml" file:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:8.0">
  <server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" ... max-parameters="2000" />
```

This works: no UT000047 any more.

But this solution is rejected by our organization (since it implies to modify all the WF services of our organization, just to make 1 page of 1 application works).

## What we'd prefer

We would prefer to increase the `max-parameter` attribute only for this application (even better: only for the HTML page).

We know that some application-specific configuration can be made through a "WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml". Such a solution would be fine for us. But (AFAIK) the `max-parameter` cannot be defined in this file.

Comment: You really need to rethink this design.  I cannot fathom a reason to have this so complicated.  Maintenance, testing, and coding have to be immensely more complicated than needed.  I would reject the configuration change too as it opens up the potential for abuse.

Comment: @stdunbar: You're right. We've first said that the application should be reconceived/rewritten in order not to generate so many HTTP params. But the product owner categorically refused...

Comment: Would your team accept a different virtual host that could be configured for just your server?  That would isolate this to a single virtual host, not all hosts.  You're dealing with the lower level Undertow configuration so it's not going to work for a single page.  Otherwise you need to consider a proxy of some sort that can handle the URL parameters and pass them a different way - like an AWS queue or something else.

Comment: @stdunbar: Thanks for your answers. The Wildfly services are managed by another team in our organization (this team could be named "ops"). I (as a "dev") am precisely looking for a solution that does not imply them to change something to their solutions...